# Where do I ask: Could Angular regarded as JavaScript templating?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I have a simple question, and I do not want it to be **off topic** on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), because it does not have a code issue; it is just a conceptual question. The question is:

> Is Angular regarded as a JavaScript templating engine?

I have tried to find any website about programmers talk on the Stack Exchange Network, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question would not be on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

It is primarily opinion-based, and [we don't accept questions like that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Why is it opinion-based? Well, first you have to agree upon a definition of what a "JavaScript templating engine" is, and once you do that, then you will trivially have your answer.

You might be interested to know that [Wikipedia regards Angular as a JavaScript templating library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating). Other opinions can be researched the same way that I found that one: by using a search engine.

Comment: Just admit that it is way easier to have someone else do the search and copy-paste the links in an answer ...

Comment: But...it isn't, @rene. I can search for myself a heckuva lot faster than I can type out a question, fend off snarky comments, and wait for an answer.

Comment: Yeah, the snarky comments kills it ... cheers! .. . ;)